# How to replace positions in a number by special characters in oracle?

Tags: oracle

My table contain column name accountnumber;

```
acctnum
-------
1234556777
2335678000
```

i want an output using oracle using sql query

```
    acctnum
    ---------
   123xxx6777
   233xxx8000
```

i tried replace function ,but i did not get the output.pls help.

Comment: Do you want to replace for first 3 characters?

Comment: yes .I want to replace first 3 positions by a special character..pls help me to find how will replace positions by special characters also

Answer (score 0):

If I did not understand wrong, This maybe help you?

```
with a as 
(select '1234567' as acctnum from dual)

select '###' || substr(acctnum,4) from a;
```

Comment: this is perfect.sir if i want to replace 4th,5th,6th position by special characters,how will i use

Comment: please helpi want to use this for our project

Comment: In  Substr(1234567,4)  statement , '4' means start 4th charecter for substring. Change it to 5,6  or what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to replace characters 4, 5 and 6 with an `x` you can do it with the `SUBSTR` function like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(acctnum, 1, 3) || 'xxx' || SUBSTR(acctnum, 7) AS acctnum
FROM mytable;
```